How to close billing in aws console
I've been using AWS for the past week and my free tier is already exhausted. the bill has summed up an amount of 85 USD. I've closed my account now. Will the services generate more billing? How can I stop the billing at this point?
I thought it would be covered in free tier. But the bill amount exceeded it. I'm clueless now

it will stop after you get account closure confirmation from AWS. if you dont get it please  contact AWS support from free method and let them know you want to close the account. They can help you with extra charges after free tire as you were not aware. They might write off some of the charges for first time . kudos

Side-note: Services in the AWS Free Tier typically have a monthly allocation, so while you might have consumed the free portions for this month, more is available the next month.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow

You can reopen your closed AWS account, AWS retains closed accounts for a certain period (usually 90 days) before permanently deleting them.
Make sure to terminate all the services that were created. This ensures you won't incur any unnecessary charges.
For the future, when you create an AWS account, set up AWS Billing Alerts to prevent similar situations from happening again.
